# Adding events and data from child React components to pass to other child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a framework for a UI that can be used for several internal applications

I would like something like a state/props class to be shared between different child elements

For example, if I wanted a Child element called MenuBar.js and another child element called ToolBar

I would like to add a button to the menu to display something on the ToolBar.js.

But I don't want to make any messy changes in the parent App.js element, because there may be dozens of buttons and callbacks in the future

In C++ I would pass an vector or entire structure by reference or pointer between different child classes and append any function pointers to this vector as more callback functions get added. Then assign those callback functions to buttons in the MenuBar

Is there a way to do this in React?

If I create a Props class in App.js that has different variables for the state of the program, and a List of callback events, pass it to all of the child elements. Then add callbacks from within those elements, will this class be passed by reference between all of the Child components?

Comment: Yes it will. And it is one of the solutions and a perfectly legit one. No need for state manager or complex logic for something as simple.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options out there.

If you need a state manager, then according to your description it can be a mobx.

Another option would be any Event Emitter library or Event Bus library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).